# How to map a `Pool` over a `Queue`?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a `multiprocessing.Pool(n, maxtasksperchild=1)` that I would like to employ performing the task of gobbling up the entries of a steadily growing `Queue`.

Suppose that `fill_q` puts a known list of things into the `Queue`, which can handily use `pool.map_async`.  However, `work` is getting things out of the `Queue`, and does not know the size of the `Queue`, and so cannot use `map`.

Ideally, when things enter the `Queue`, if there are any pool workers available, they will immediately gobble up things from the `Queue`, otherwise, the pool will block until a worker becomes available.

Here is an example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time
import functools

C = SOME_CONSTANT_TO_MAKE_IT_TAKE_A_FEW_SECONDS = 0.3

manager = mp.Manager()
q = manager.Queue()

def work(q):
    todo = q.get()
    time.sleep(random.random()*C)

def fill_q(q, item):
    for i in range(random.randint(1,5)):
        q.put(i)
    time.sleep(random.random()*C)

put_pool = mp.Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)
get_pool = mp.Pool(4, maxtasksperchild=1)

put_pool.map_async(functools.partial(fill_q, q), range(100))

#This line doesn't quite do what I want to do
results = get_pool.map_async(work, [q]*100)

print(len(results.get()))
```

The line after `#This line...` gets a bunch of workers working incessantly on `work`, which is what I want.  They block until there are things in `q`, which is also what I want.  However, it fails to empty the `q`, since I don't know a priori how many objects I will need to map over.

Some things to note are that I do *not* know how many things will end up in `q`, so I can't map get_pool over a `range`, for example.  However, I *do* know when `q` has stopped growing, since the only thing filling `q` is the `.map_async` call to `fill_q`.  Once that joins, `q` will stop filling up, and so once it is empty I can more-or-less safely get my `results`.

Possibly a `Pool` is simply a wrong-headed solution to this.  Alternative solutions to `Pool`s are acceptable, but it seems that `Pool`s provide a great deal of the process management that I am looking for.

How do I get a `Pool` to map over a `Queue`?

Comment: Because I'm sure this will come up, my processes are long-running and memory-hungry and they sadly do not do a good job of cleaning up after themselves.  It is important, therefore, that they close after completing their task and respawn afterward (hence the `maxtasksperchild=1`)

Comment: I followed these two guides to get me going:
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html for general mp usage
https://pymotw.com/3/multiprocessing/communication.html for producer / consumer design patterns